# Do adjoints of enriched functors preserve the enriched structure?

Tags: adjoint-functors, enriched-category-theory

Is there is any reason in general for adjoints of enriched functors to preserve the enriched structure of categories?

The specific example I'm thinking of is the following:

Fix a commutative ring $R$. Let $C$ and $D$ be categories enriched in $R$-modules (i.e. $Hom(x,y)$ has the structure of an $R$-module). Let $F: C \longrightarrow D$ be an $R$-linear functor (i.e. is a map of $R$-modules on the Homs), and suppose that $F$ admits a right adjoint $G: D \longrightarrow C$. Does it follow that $G$ is $R$-linear?

Comment: Is the isomorphism $Hom_D(F(x),y)\cong Hom_C(x,G(y))$ an isomorphism of R-modules or just a bijection?

Comment: @myself: It is automatically R-linear since its inverse is given by applying F and then postcomposing with the counit, and both are R-linear